# Filter view by passing a date via URL

Tags: views

I have created a view and I want to show filtered posts passing arguments via the URL. Example:

http://mysite.com/press/2012-01

I want to show all press posts created in January'2012.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Check out Taming the Beast at nodeone.se (http://dev.nodeone.se/en/taming-the-beast-learn-views-with-nodeone) for an excellent and comprehensive tutorial on all things Views.

Comment: FYI, in Drupal we call it argument. `arg`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the core Views example *Archive* (`admin/structure/views/view/archive/edit`) which is disabled by default.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Contextual Filters](http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/using-drupal-contextual-filters-views) in order to pass arguments to the view.